# Send email on 500 Error Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, application-error

If a 500 exception error occurs in my MVC application I want to send an email to alert the website owners.

I have discovered the Application_Application_Error method on the global.asax.cs file, which fires when ever the application has an error.

What I want to know is, is it safe to send an email in this method, what happens if an unexpected error happens? Will the application end up in an infinate loop? kill my webserver?

Has anyone done something like this before, is there a better way?

Comment: _"what happens if an unexpected error happens? Will the application end up in an infinate loop? kill my webserver?"_ - It depends on what unexpected error will happen. _"is it safe to send an email in this method"_ - I don't see anything wrong with it, it's just a some kind of logging, so you are logging specific error to email.

Comment: *"Will the application end up in an infinate loop?"* - No.  But if there's an error sending the email then of course the email won't be sent.  You'd probably want to wrap your logic in a try/catch and handle such errors however you define.

Comment: I think you should not send mail for all the exceptions. You can create log file or save it in database. Send mails only for the particular exceptions or custom exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MVC, why not use an action filter that you can add to your entire app?

```
public class CustomErrorHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        try{
            //Send email
        }
        catch{
           //Swallow...
        }
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then in your `FilterConfig.cs`

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
   filters.Add(new CustomErrorHandler());       
}
```

If you swallow the exception in the filter then it doesn't bubble up and create any loops in your app. Plus you can have more fine grain control over your error handling.

Comment: It's not the best idea to swallow exceptions. You will never know that your mailing is broken.

Comment: The email error is not important for bubbling up, if the app falls over then I'd much rather get the root cause error stack trace than a useless error that my error logging failed.

Comment: Email error is important, because it shows that your logging is not working as expected, this error should be written to the usual log file at least. It's possible now to have a silent crash, if mailing fails and all the exceptions are ignored.

Comment: Writing the email error to a log file is akin to swallowing it, as you wouldn't ever want the email error to bubble up and overwrite the actual exception being handled by the filter...

Answer (score 0):

Usually some kind of library is used to perform logging: [Nlog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial), [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or others.
And most of such libraries have an ability to perform email notifications. You could use this knowledge — perform simple and consistent logging in your app and achieve goals with proper configuration for logger of your choice.

This could be done with use of:

- [Email sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email) for serilog
- [Email target](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target) for nlog
- [Smtp Appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#smtpappender) for log4net
- etc